# multiple clients one server TCP C++

Tags: c++

when I run this code it gives me output "Enter your nick name:", but not helo why I haven't found any errors in it but code strucks

```
    void* ThreadFunc(void* client_socket){
                    char nick[100]="helo";

        cout<<"Enter your nick name: "<<endl;
        cout<<nick;
    }
server socket from command line argument
    c_socket=new int[1];

            while(true){

                newsocket=accept(Welcomesocket,(sockaddr *) &serverstorage,&size);
                pthread_t t;

                *c_socket=newsocket;
call ThreadFunc

                if(pthread_create(&t,NULL,ThreadFunc,(void *)c_socket)<0){
                    cout<<"Error in creating thread";
                    return 1;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cout<<nick;
```

to

```
cout<<nick<<flush;
```

as `nick` will just be in the buffer and not written to `stdout`